# Turning location services on and off a few times a day drains the battery more than keeping location services on?

Tags: android, location, battery, power-management, android-powermanager

I am trying to implement a power saving app for Android and I can't figure out if turning on and off location services periodically, a few times a day, not very often, is worse for the battery than keeping location services always on. Can anybody explain me if it is or not? Or does anybody know how to measure the amount of energy lost for location services?

I tried using battery historian for measuring consumption but is oriented on apps and other components. I couldn't find a way to obtain power consumed by a specific thing, you can obtain just the overall consumption in a specific period of time.